# Get Edit Links Created through CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom

Is there a programmatic way of accessing through PowerShell/CSOM  to get the Edit links created for  the documents

[image]

Comment: look for ObjectSharing information for list item. In that object you will get this link. SP.ObjectSharingInformation.getListItemSharingInformation

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **CreateOrganizationSharingLink** to get the URL of the document.

```
 public static ClientResult<string> CreateOrganizationSharingLink(
     ClientRuntimeContext context,
     string url,
     bool isEditLink
    )
```

You need to specify the full URL of the document in the parameter.

If you want the edit link, keep the isEditLink parameter value set to true

The sample code is as below:

```
var docEditLink = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web.CreateOrganizationSharingLink(context, 
"https://tenant-name.sharepoint.com/sites/testLibrary/Documents/test.docx", true);

context.ExecuteQuery();

var editLink = docEditLink.Value;
```

Comment: Thank you Anuja ,Presently i am trying to get an inventory report of all the documents in a site using CSOM where for each item i am reading the metadata associated with it .Is there a way that i can get the link without actually creating the edit link